# Content from library is not deployed to UWP app

Tags: .net, visual-studio, uwp

I am not sure if this is a bug or a proper behavior. To reproduce:

- (in Visual Studio) create UWP project
- create netstandard project
- add a content file to netstandard project (mark it as 'Content' *and* set it to 'Copy if newer')
- from UWP project add reference to netstandard project
- run in debug mode (without .NET Native tool chain)

Result: Content file will be copied to bin/Debug folder on build, but it will NOT be copied/deployed to bin/Debug/AppX folder.

1. Why does content file get copied on build, but it doesn't get deployed in the end?
2. How can I properly add content to referenced project so that it will get deployed to UWP app?
3. If this is a bug, where is the best place to report it?

I am using Visual Studio 2017 v15.4.1 on Windows 10 Fall Creators Update

Answer (score 2):

In the class library, the file gets copied on build because of "Copy to output" is set to "Copy if newer", not because its Build Action is Content.

Add a new .resx file to the class library, then add this file (I assume it is an image) using the designer.

Then use it from the UWP app like this (NewFolder is the containing folder of the .resx file).

```
byte[] data = ClassLibrary1.NewFolder.Resource1.IMG1;
```

Note: I have checked the API list of .NET Standard 2.0 from this blog post [Announcing UWP Support for .NET Standard 2.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/10/10/announcing-uwp-support-for-net-standard-2-0/), `ResourceManager` has the `GetObject` method, which is used to retrieve binary data like image. In version 1.3, `ResourceManager` has only `GetString` method, which is used to retrieve string literals. So, you need to make the Class Library target .NET Standard 2.0.

[image]

Comment: Upvoted as it is viable alternative in some cases. Unfortunately embedding content into a .dll is not always desired solution. For example #1 embedded native dll cannot be loaded from memory, but it has to be saved to disk first. Or #2 if dynamic loading of big content is required. #3 With msbuild we can use wildcards to import content and use conditional compilation rules. You doesn't really answer why it gets copied on build but not deployed, if added to library. If content is added to UWP project directly using the same method, it gets both copied on build and deployed.

Comment: For why it does not get deployed to AppX, I thought of that but felt I cannot explain it well enough. The msbuild treats different project types differently, in UWP, a file marked as content is copied to AppX folder and then bundled into the AppX package, but for the referenced library, the tool is not that smart... But like you I just observe this without really understand the details, or finding some docs to backup the observation.

Comment: "The tool is not that smart", sounds like a bug to me. I cannot think of the purpose why content is copied to the build folder of the UWP project, but not deployed in the end. I searched, but cannot find documentation that would explain this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

> Result: Content file will be copied to bin/Debug folder on build, but it will NOT be copied/deployed to bin/Debug/AppX folder.
>
> Why does content file get copied on build, but it doesn't get deployed in the end?

You have added the content to `netstandard` project (`Copy if newer`). So it will be copy to Debug folder. This behaviour is [similar](http://Building%20Xamarin.Forms%20Apps%20with%20.NET%20Standard) to `PCL`. If you want verify it, you could add the content file to `Xamarin`share project and check the content file last path. It will be the same as the above results.
For more you could refer to [**Comparison to Portable Class Libraries**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#comparison-to-portable-class-libraries).

> 2.How can I properly add content to referenced project so that it will get deployed to UWP app?

Since .NET Standard Library is similar to `PCL`, you could refer to some document of [`Xamarin.Forms`](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/). For example, working with [`EmbeddedResource`](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images/#Embedded_Images).

I have verified this. It also works in .NET Standard Library.

**Example**
Add image file to `Standard`.

- add a content file to netstandard project (mark it as `Embedded resource` and set it to `Do not copy`)
- from UWP project add reference to netstandard project.

**Class1.cs**

```
public class Class1
{
    public static Stream GetImage()
    {
        var assembly = typeof(Class1).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
        Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("ClassLibrary1.timg.jpg");
        return stream;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{           
    BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
    var stream = Class1.GetImage();
    await bitmap.SetSourceAsync(stream.AsRandomAccessStream());
    MyImg.Source = bitmap;
}
```

Comment: "The content file has been compiled into Class.library.dll" I'm not sure what you mean here, but content file is not compiled in any way.

Comment: As you know the `netstandard`  library will be used as library object finally. And the content file  is the object's field(`ClassLibrary1.timg.jpg`).

Comment: Object's field? OK trying to clear this up, lets say netstandard project is named "ClassLibrary1" and the content file is named "file1.jpg". End result will be two separate files inside build folder: "ClassLibrary1.dll" and "file1.jpg". Inside AppX folder there will only be "ClassLibrary1.dll"; "file1.jpg" will be missing and is not embedded inside "ClassLibrary1.dll".

Comment: Note: I am taking about marking "file1.jpg" as content, not embedded resource!

Comment: Yep, I found that you have reported this on the github. And the related team has open the thread. Please monitor the state of [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1690).